# Outlook Shared Calendar Requests

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

I got the below request from an end-user.  Wondering if this is possible?

> I have a calendar that i use for PTO requests that everyone has access
>   to see, But i still have to do the manual paper requests..because i
>   just gave them viewer permissions so they don't delete or add anything
>   without my approval.. just wondering how i can get it so that they can
>   request a date and a notification be sent to me. i did give them the
>   option to create and edit their own but i get two notification then!

My understanding is that she'd like them to be able to submit a request to make changes to the calendar that she gets a notification for on weather she can accept or decline those changes.

Is that possible? I'm definitely not an outlook expert and upon searching google, I didn't come across much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative.  I was actually slightly off with my first answer.

Try this instead...Have her create the PTO requests as **Meetings** and invite everyone on her team to those "Meetings".

This will give them all the ability to propose new times in the schedule of which she would have to approve.

This will prevent users from changing up her personal calendar since a meeting is a shared event.

Comment: Thank you, i've went back to the end-user with this info and will go from there. I appreciate you taking the time to help out. =-)

Comment: @Ryan Let me know how it goes.  Cause it can be a bit tricky!

Comment: @Ryan I made a bit of a mistake after some testing, but I have an alternative.  Edited the answer